# nginx location with no code being skipped over

Tags: nginx, configuration

I'm trying to get nginx to **not** place some headers in the response for a specific set of files. In general we want to set header to avoid caching, but there is a bug with font-awesome in IE where it breaks if it's set to not cache. We've deicded to avoid caching for font files.

Here's the code:

```
location /app-name {
  alias   /usr/local/nginx-sites/<app-folder>/current;

  location ~ /app-name/(.*\.(woff|ttf))$ {
    add_header X-FONT "$1"; # if I comment this out, then I get the headers below
  }

  add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
  add_header Pragma "no-cache";
  add_header Expires "0";

  index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

As the code is, it works. However, if I comment out `add_header X-FONT "$1";` it goes back to serving the file with the unwanted headers. I'd rather not have to pass in a random header so that nginx will do what I expect. Seems a bit pointless.

With the X-FONT header:

```
> GET /<app-name>/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.1.19
< Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 07:50:17 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 65452
< Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 01:56:10 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-FONT: fonts/fontawesome-webfont.92e68ff4.woff
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Without the X-FONT header:

```
> GET /<app-name>/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.1.19
< Date: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 07:53:15 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 65452
< Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Aug 2015 01:56:10 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

We're running: `nginx/1.1.19`. I also tried: `nginx/1.6.2 (Ubuntu)` in a VM with the same results.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Simply don't use nested locations

Comment: or try `add_header x-font "";`

Comment: Adding that empty header did it. I don't like that I have that header (that I'm technically not using) in the config, but it beats sending it to the clients. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722906/5269040), you should be able to use a negative look behind syntax to exclude woff and ttf file extensions from the cache headers being sent:

```
location ~ .+(?<!\.woff)$ {
    location ~ .+(?<!\.ttf)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        add_header Pragma "no-cache";
        add_header Expires "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer. But when I tried it I got `pcre_compile() failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length in ".+(?<!\.(woff|ttf))$" at ")$"`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've changed my post to use nested conditions. In my nginx environment configtest succeeds with the new nested configuration.