# Nginx config: match everything except for multiple extensions

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am wanting to cache all files except for "php", "phtml" and "html". After some research, I put this together to attempt it the best I could:

```
location ~ .+(?<!\.(php|phtml|html))$ {
        expires 336h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}
```

But Nginx config test fails with this:

```
nginx: [emerg] pcre_compile() failed: lookbehind assertion is not
fixed length in ".+(?<!\.(php|html|phtml))$" at ")$" in
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:19
```

Elsewhere I have php, phtml, and html set to not cache. That is working fine.

Places that almost got me there:

https://serverfault.com/a/334871/117054

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722906/508558

Comment: If php, phtml, and html are set to not cache, then you should be able to add your cache directives as defaults near the the top of your server stanza and let your php, phtml, and html setting override the default cache settings.

Comment: @ColeTierney - Awesome, it works, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it help!